# Can't upgrade manually installed package

Tags: upgrade, thunderbird

Sometime ago I manually reverted to an old version of Thunderbird (31.6). I now want to upgrade to the latest stable version.

Synaptic says I'm on 1.38.5, which I am not.

`apt-get install thunderbird` gives me

```
thunderbird is already the newest version.
thunderbird set to manually installed.
```

`apt-mark auto thunderbird` makes no difference.

Does anyone know how can I tell the system that I'm on version 31.6, not 38.5, and hence how can I receive updates automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't update the package manager's view of your system when you "manually reverted to an old version of thunderbird", it thinks you're running the current version. Rather than trying to tell the package management system about your old version, you could simply reinstall the current version with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall thunderbird
```

which `man apt-get` documents as:

```
--reinstall
           Re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest
           version. Configuration Item: APT::Get::ReInstall.
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I did try removal and reinstall via synaptic, which made no difference. Neither did apt-get as per your suggestion. However it said it had upgraded to 38, which was when I realised I must have a second install of thunderbird. I confess I did a very hasty downgrade because I was in the middle of working and the latest upgrade at the time had problems with encryption and authentication. Time to go and figure how exactly what I did, but your suggestion has lead me to the solution thanks.